# How to run Maven from Java?

Tags: java, maven, maven-embedder

I want to execute Maven command from Java for development of a plugin. I tried `maven-embedder` but looks like it is now not supported. Is someone aware of some other tool which can be used?

Comment: If you are developing a Maven Plugin you should take a deep look into the Maven Invoker Plugin to make integration test for the plugin

Comment: @Paul Verest, my answer is not working for you?

Comment: @MariuszS In Eclipse plugin embedding Maven will make it heavy, I want let user to select the same version he/she has on PC https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.maven . There were only 2 option named: embedder and lower level `exec()`. A good answer would be from those who really accomplishes and can compare or give a new option.

Comment: @PaulVerest I have used both options in my project and prefer embedded version. Maven is heavy, and it will always make program using it heavier. Do you ask for something like Maven Light? There is no such thing at all, maven embedder configuration from my answer has minimal configuration. You can disable wagon for smaller and lighter maven version.

Comment: Maven Invoker Plugin does not look useful in all instances, thus I have written a plugin using MavenCLI, with some help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410706/error-when-execute-mavencli-in-the-loop-maven-embedder with my added comments.

Answer (score 58):

A simple invocation API : maven-invoker.

Project documentation : http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/

Usage : http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile( new File( "/path/to/pom.xml" ) );
request.setGoals( Arrays.asList( "clean", "install" ) );

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.execute( request );
```

Comment: Is there any way that we can run `maven` plugins on a system where both `java` and `maven` is not present. Please have a look at the question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911102/how-to-execute-maven-plugins-from-gradle-without-having-maven-and-java-installed]

Answer (score 17):

## Use [Maven Embedder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/index.html)

Maven embedder is still supported and easy to configure, so this is better option for you.

### Java code

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
cli.doMain(new String[]{"clean", "install"}, "project_dir", System.out, System.out);
```

### Project configuration

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Fully working example: https://github.com/mariuszs/maven-cli-example

Comment: Can the maven embedder be downloaded as a jar if the project using it isn't using maven?

Comment: Yes, you can use this jar https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1012436/maven-jar-with-dependencies.jar from example project and invoke maven build with `java -jar maven-jar-with-dependencies.jar` from maven project directory.

Comment: no, what I mean is, can you use maven embedder in a project that doesn't use maven? and how?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible but compliacted :) Prepare `pom.xml` for this project and run maven embedder on it. The compliacted part is preparing `pom.xml`.

Comment: @MariuszS Is there any way that we can run `maven` plugins on a system where both `java` and `maven` is not present. Please have a look at the question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911102/how-to-execute-maven-plugins-from-gradle-without-having-maven-and-java-installed]

Comment: @tbodt: You can download ALL maven artifacts simply from maven central manually or by some other mechanism, e.g. gradle or ivy. In this case just go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-embedder/3.1.1

Comment: I got a `NoSuchMethodError` during (an internal call of) `isThreadConfigurationPresent()Z`. What solved the problem for me was changing the version of `maven-embedder` from `3.1.1.` to `3.2.1.`.

Comment: how to run it behind proxy?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410706/error-when-execute-mavencli-in-the-loop-maven-embedder for why more work can be required, especially inside a custom Maven plugin!

Answer (score 5):

Maven embedder is indeed no longer supported (only hudson still uses it). But, as in hudson, there are several other ways to run maven. You could simply run maven as an external program:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mvn clean install");
```

Or you could consider creating an [ant script for maven.](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html)
This script could then be called either as an external program or (if you need more control) adding ant to your classpath and calling the Antrunner.

**UPDATE**

Maven embedder is now supported again so that is your best option.

Comment: Maven embedder is cross platform, but your first solution is just for Unix. For Windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674220/running-maven-from-java-code-in-windows

Comment: This will not execute, as executed process is not shell, so there is JAVA_HONE, MAVEN_HOME etc settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397170/java-process-launched-with-runtime-getruntime-exec-cannot-create-temp-file

Comment: I would think that mvn needing to be in the path goes without saying; no need to downvote for that.

Comment: This will fork a separate process for Maven in it's own JVM. MariuszS' answer is the proper way to do it through Java itself. Invoking Maven through `Runtime` is also an option, but it would be less efficient as  it will require more resources.

Comment: The OP asked for alternatives to maven embedder!

Comment: @StijnGeukens Yes, because he thinks Embeedder is not supported. This is not true.

Comment: At the time of writing (2 years ago) Maven embedder was officially not supported anymore. Now it indeed seems to be supported again.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by others, you can use the Maven Embedder.

It might not be trivial to get all the proper dependencies correctly: of course, the one for the Maven Embedder itself is easy and you get Java code that compiles but fails at runtime because it cannot find some classes dynamically.

I recently wrote a tutorial on how to use the Maven Embedder (it also comes with a few JUnit tests): https://www.lorenzobettini.it/2024/02/running-maven-from-java-the-maven-embedder/

I report here the needed dependencies:

```xml
<properties>
...
    <maven-embedder-version>3.9.6</maven-embedder-version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-embedder-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- For Maven logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
<!--
    Required due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6561
    Otherwise, you get the error:
    [main] WARN Sisu - Error injecting: org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper
    com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
    1) No implementation for RepositorySystem was bound.
        while locating DefaultProjectBuildingHelper
-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-embedder-version}</version>
</dependency>
<!--
    Required to let Maven download artifacts.
    Otherwise, you get errors of the shape:
    Plugin ... or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for ...:
    Could not transfer artifact ... from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
    No connector factories available.
-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resolver-connector-basic</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resolver-transport-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Note the needed `maven-compat` (better to keep it in sync with the `maven-embedder`'s version) and the other requirements. Again, the `resolver` requirements might have to be upgraded if you upgrade the Maven Embedder version.

Creating a Java code that runs Maven is then easy:

```java
package com.examples;

import org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli;

public class MavenEmbedderRunner {
    public int run(String baseDir, String...args) {
        MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
        // Required to avoid the error:
        // "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set."
        System.setProperty("maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory", baseDir);
        return cli.doMain(args, baseDir, System.out, System.err);
    }
}
```

See the above mentioned tutorial for further details and tests.