# Running Maven from Java code in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, maven, cmd

I am trying to run maven from my java class based on this suggestion:

[How to run maven from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mvn");
```

but I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

mvn is on my path and I can run it just fine from cmd:

```
C:\Users\m>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_20, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre
...
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Better use Maven embedder, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19904341/516167

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd \c mvn");
```

**Edit:**
In response to the firs question...

Yes. See: [Process#getInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29). Basically you will need to consume the output from the sub-process being created.

I also like this article: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: I need to do: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C mvn"); but I don't get any output in my console, is it necessary to pipe that out somehow?

Comment: it produces if:            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );

            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

Answer (score 7):

Use `mvn.cmd` instead of `mvn` or `mvn.bat`.
It works fine (on Windows OS).
But keep in mind the **OS compatibility** issue (Windows/Linux).

Answer (score 2):

You can view mvn.bat and echo which java command is actually executed and run it directly.

In mvn.bat:

`%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR% "-Dclassworlds.conf=%M2_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=%M2_HOME%" %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%`

In my machine executing dependency:tree is:

`"java -classpath \"C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar\" -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=\"C:\dev\tools\apache-maven-3.1.1\" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher dependency:tree"`

Answer (score 1):

Error 2 means that the executable cannot be found by the JRE environment. This means that the PATH environment variable does not contain the Maven binary directory.

2 choices here:

1. Make sure that the Maven bin directory is in the PATH environment variable
2. Use an absolute path to the mvn command.

Alternatively, this could also be due to a permission denied, but it is less likely the case.

Comment: I added C:\User\username\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin to my system PATH, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try restarting ide and possibly your computer.  I followed the instructions from Guillame as well, and also experienced the same issue after i added maven to the PATH.  However, once I restarted my computer, Maven was found on the PATH and Eclipse was able to run the maven command.  Hope this helps...