# Error when execute MavenCli in the loop (maven-embedder)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-embedder

What is the problem when I execute the maven command in the loop ? The goal is to update the version of pom.xml of the list of bundles. The first iteration, maven execute correctly (update pom.xml), but it makes error for all item after.

```
for (String bundlePath: bundlesToUpdate)
{
    MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
String[] arguments = {
    "-Dtycho.mode=maven", 
        "org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version", 
    "-DgenerateBackupPoms=false", 
    "-DnewVersion=" + version};
    int result = cli.doMain(arguments, bundlePath, System.out, System.err);
}
```

Same error with the code:

```
`MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
for (String bundlePath: bundlesToUpdate) 
{
    String[] arguments = {
    "-Dtycho.mode=maven", 
    "org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version", 
    "-DgenerateBackupPoms=false", 
    "-DnewVersion=" + version};
int result = cli.doMain(arguments, bundlePath, System.out, System.err);
}`
```

First time, it's ok:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.tycho.versions.manipulation.PomManipulator -   pom.xml//project/version: 2.2.6-SNAPSHOT => 2.2.7-SNAPSHOT
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Reactor Summary:
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - XXXX project   ....................... SUCCESS [  0.216 s]
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - com.sungard.valdi.bus.fixbroker.client.bnp ........ SKIPPED
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - XXX project Feature ...................... SKIPPED
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD SUCCESS
```

After the errors are:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Error executing Maven.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - java.util.NoSuchElementException
  role: org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher
roleHint: 
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Caused by: null
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Error executing Maven.
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher
roleHint:
```

Comment: I found the solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to use Maven Invoker and it works fine for the same functionality:

```
    public class MavenInvoker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoHeadException, GitAPIException 
{
    MavenInvoker toto = new MavenInvoker();

    toto.updateVersionMavenInvoker("2.2.8-SNAPSHOT", "TECHNICAL\\WEB" );
}

private InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
private DefaultInvoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();

public InvocationResult updateVersionMavenInvoker(String newVersion, String folderPath)
{
    InvocationResult result = null;
    request.setPomFile( new File(folderPath+"\\pom.xml" ) );

    String version =  "-DnewVersion="+newVersion;
    request.setGoals( Arrays.asList("-Dtycho.mode=maven", 
            "org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version", 
            "-DgenerateBackupPoms=false", 
            version) );
    try {
        result = invoker.execute( request );
    } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: The question was about how to use maven embedder. I think it is possible.
The solution you provided is using another library. So I dont know if it should be tagged as the answer.
I personally have a similar requirement and prefer maven-embedder over invoker, cause the latest involves IO operations to write/read a pom.xml from the system, which is not necessary for my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me inside a custom maven plugin (using Maven 3.5.0):

```
ClassRealm classRealm = (ClassRealm) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli(classRealm.getWorld());
cli.doMain( ... );
```

The plexus Launcher [sets the context class loader](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-classworlds/blob/4e4ccaae2041b04d8808d1125151343b1ba221e4/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher.java#L287) to its `ClassRealm`, which has access to the "global" `ClassWorld`.

Not sure how stable that solution is, but so far looking good.

Used imports:

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorld;
import org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm;
import org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli;
```

Comment: it gives classcast exception

Comment: This was useful, but I discovered the hard way that I had to do:

    final ClassRealm classRealm = (ClassRealm) 
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    final ClassWorld classWorld = classRealm.getWorld();
    classWorld.disposeRealm("maven.ext");
    final MavenCli cli = new MavenCli(classWorld);

Comment: It's such a pity that the official documentation is so damned minimal as to be near useless, including the Javadocs(!), as is sadly a lot of Apache, with Maven seemly one of the worst parts, but at least I can look at the Maven plugins source code on Github...

Comment: I've come to the bitter conclusion that MavenCli isn't usable in a plugin, the logs get messed up, so IDEA thinks it has prematurely stopped!  I had a look at the Apache Maven Invoker library, used by the Maven Invoker plugin, and it builds a CLI string for the Maven EXE and runs that!  This is obvious lack of confidence in their own libraries!!!

Comment: I feel you. I was assuming the solution might not be stable long term. Unfortunately I don't know more, haven't used that code again with newer Maven versions.

Answer (score 0):

See the email thread for a more detail explanation: https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/sisu-users/msg00063.html

It seems the correct way is to give `MainCli` a `ClassWorld` instance on construction so it can maintain a proper state through multiple calls.

Example:

```
final ClassWorld classWorld = new ClassWorld("plexus.core", getClass().getClassLoader());
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli(classWorld);
String[] arguments = {
    "-Dtycho.mode=maven", 
        "org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version", 
    "-DgenerateBackupPoms=false", 
    "-DnewVersion=" + version};
int result = cli.doMain(arguments, bundlePath, System.out, System.err);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me inside a maven plugin. But it lead me into the right direction, see my answer. Thanks!