# How can I run mvn exec:java from inside Java

Tags: java, junit, maven-3

I would like to build a JUnit integration test that launches a Java process (Spring based) and then makes calls against that process.

If I would call this from the command line I would launch the Java process by calling 
`mvn exec:java -DmainClass=myClass -Dblahblah` from the command line in my pom directory

Is there any way to call that exec:main from inside my Java tester class, so that my tester can execute calls against process and validate results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run maven from java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [maven-invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/)

Here is the what you need

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile( new File( "/path/to/pom.xml" ) );
request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "exec:java -DmainClass=com.vgrazi.MyClass -Dparam1=value1" ) );

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.execute( request );
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to send in the -D parameters?

Comment: try with http://maven.apache.org/shared-archives/maven-invoker-2.1.1/apidocs/org/apache/maven/shared/invoker/DefaultInvocationRequest.html#addShellEnvironment%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Actually I just added my -D parameters right at the end of the string, and it worked. In other words "exec:java -Dblahblah -Dblahmore". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Maven invocation API](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html)

The code is going to be something similar to the following:

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile( new File( "/path/to/pom.xml" ) );
request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "install" ) );

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.execute( request );
```