# create maven project programmatically

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I’m trying to execute these commands inside a web service (jersey 2):

```
cmd /c cd FOLDER
 &&
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.hybris.datahub
-DarchetypeArtifactId=datahub-extension-archetype
-DarchetypeVersion=ARCHETYPEVERSION
-DsdkVersion=SDKVERSION
-DgroupId=XXX.XXX.XXX
-DartifactId=AZERTY
-Dversion=VERSION
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

And after it finish, I change what I need to change then I execute these commands:

```
cmd /c cd FOLDER/AZERTY
 &&
mvn clean install
```

Method that executes these commands:

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
            if(line.contains("BUILD"))
                result.add(line.substring(7));
        for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
            if(result.get(i).equals("BUILD FAILURE"))
                return "BUILD FAILURE";
        return "BUILD SUCCESS";
    } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I’m using Tomcat 7 as a server.

My problem that this command executes half of the time and don't finish to the end and I read in an article that we can use `org.apache.maven` to create a Maven project and deploy it programmatically but I didn’t find an example.

Please help me what I need to do (sorry for my english ^^”)

Comment: See [How to run maven from java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java).

Comment: @gerold thx, it worked