# How to run maven command from java?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to java and wants to run maven command with attributes from java code. How can I achieve this?

Here is command that is executing from script file.

$MVN test -Dtest=$SCRIPT_PATH  -Dcapability.app=$APP_FILE_PATH -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true >> $LOGFILE_PATH;

I want to execute this same thing from java code.

please help me if any one knows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose you're trying to achieve?

Anyway, you may use the Runtime library for this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mvn clean install -DmyAwsomeProperty=awsome");
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: I want to execute this command from java.

$MVN test -Dtest=$SCRIPT_PATH  -Dcapability.app=$APP_FILE_PATH -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true >> $LOGFILE_PATH;