# MAVEN JAVA equivalent code

Tags: java, maven

**Equivalent java code for:**

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -
DgroupId=com.google.code
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

Can someone please suggest an equivalent java code for the above lines Maven command.

Comment: There is no equivalent. This installs a file in the local maven repository, why should java be able to do this?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java#19904341

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run maven from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java)

Comment: I need to install 3rd party jar via this. I don't think maven embedder can perform such task

Comment: How can I use Maven invoker or Maven embedder to install 3rd party jars

Comment: Bad Idea...better use a repository manager and install those jars there. Afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies.

Comment: You dont want use maven? So what do you mean with equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it is the right idea to do this, but if you really want to execute above command from Maven, why not just use `ProcessBuilder` and call the external Java command?

Comment: I agree process builder is an approch, but it might lead to vulnerabilities  .Waht if I use maven invoker with ether for the same purpose