# Is it possible to programmatically call a maven build?

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator

I have a project that is calling a maven plugin (open-api-generator) to make a build based on an api specification. I don't want to share the project but I'd like to create a jar that somewhat simulate a "mvn compile" using an internal maven pom.xml.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have maven installed if course this is possible, cd inside the project folder call: mvn compile and that should be all

Comment: Perhaps you can use class [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute `mvn` command? Alternatively, perhaps use the classes in the [`java.util.jar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) package to create a JAR file.

Comment: Use Maven Embedder.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java

Answer (score 1):

Code :

```
MavenCli obj = new MavenCli();
obj.doMain(new String[]{"compile"}, "project_dir", System.out, System.out);
P
```

Add :

1. maven-embedder
2. aether-connector-wagon and
3. wagon-http-lightweight

dependencies in your pom.xml.

Comment: This seems what I'm searching for, I'll try it and mark as correct if it works! But how to make it point to a file inside of the jar itself?

Comment: Replace `project_dir` with the path to the file. Somewhat like "/src/main/test/MavenFile".

Answer (score 0):

Programatically it is possible to call the Shell command. For example with:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "mvn compile /foo/bar");
```